# Search and replace legacy background color

Tags: javascript, html, css, legacy

I'm working with some old HTML and CSS...

The code looks something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table.highlight {
    BACKGROUND: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<table class="highlight"><tr><td>test</td></tr></table>
</html>
```

Assuming the DOM code is read-only and the only fix is a code snippet that runs **after** the DOM has loaded, how would one hunt down these "yellow" colors and replace them?

I've tried to look for `<table>.style.BACKGROUND`, `<table>.style.background` and `<table>.style.backgroundColor` to no avail yet the color appears correctly in the web browser.

When I echo the contents of `<table>.style` yellow doesn't appear anywhere.  Is there a way to access these old, legacy CSS components?

I can successfully change the color by setting `<table>.style.backgroundColor`, but I'm having trouble locating the `yellow` to begin with.  All attempts to read the CSS return blank.

I'm testing in Google Chrome and Firefox.  Both return `undefined` or `""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('table')].forEach(e => {
  // if the background-color is yellow then change it to red
  if (getComputedStyle(e)['background-color'] === 'rgb(255, 255, 0)') 
    e.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
})
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table.highlight {
      BACKGROUND: yellow;
    }
    
    table.highlight2 {
      BACKGROUND: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<table class="highlight">
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="highlight">
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="highlight2">
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment/querySelectorAll) to locate all the elements and then process them?

If you're adding a script to the page and you need to wait until the DOM is loaded add the script to just before `</body`>. But this can be run in the browser consoles too.

```js
const yellow = document.querySelectorAll('table.highlight');

// Example: wait 1s and change the yellow tables to blue
setTimeout(() => yellow.forEach(el => el.style.background = 'blue'), 1000);
```

```css
table.highlight { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<table class="highlight"><tr><td>test1</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>test2</td></tr></table>
<table class="highlight"><tr><td>test3</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('table.highlight')` works slightly better than just looping through all the tables.  Thanks!